# When to increase minor version with SEMVER?

Tags: semantic-versioning

I have a website I'm developing. I try to use SEMVER with any changes I make. Sometimes I'm not sure when I need to bump up the minor version. For example,

I have my website/app at `v0.9.0`. I have this deployed on a production site. One day, I decide to add some new functionality to the website. I add my new functionality, test it and deploy it and it works great. Since this is not a bug fix, does that mean I need to go from `v0.9.0` to `v1.0.0`? So essentially, if I'm at `vX.0.0`, it only takes 10 new features to be independently added (no matter the size) in order to go to version `X+1` ?

It seems like there should be some way to incrementally increase the minor version. I see a lot of people do `v0.10.0` as the next version.

Is that the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Jake, it does not mean you need to go to version 1.0.0.   The next minor version after version 0.9.0 would be 0.10.0.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/semantic-versioning for a nice intro.